# Can I use the iPhone's cellular internet while connected to the Apple TV?

Tags: iphone, appletv, internet, cellular-data

I need to be able to access the internet during presentations involving the Apple TV and the iPhone, using the Apple TV as the AV link from the phone.

My experience has been that connecting to a wifi network disables the data connection to my carrier.  In many cases the wifi network I attach the phone and the apple TV to have internet access, so it's no problem.

I anticipate having to present in a situation where the wifi network won't have internet access.

Is there a way I can set up the iPhone and Apple TV so I can use the phone's internet data while still connected to the Apple TV?